# The specified record cannot be mapped to a managed value class

Tags: c#, dynamic, com, vb6, createinstance

Hi have a vb6 project "PROJVB6" with a class "CLASSVB6" with this content:

```
...

Public Type ActualParametersType_DOCUMENTI
    Codice As Variant
    Numreg As Variant
End Type
...
Private Gvar_ActualParameters           As ActualParametersType_DOCUMENTI
...
Public Property Let ActualParameters(RHS As ActualParametersType_DOCUMENTI)
    On Error Resume Next

    Gvar_ActualParameters = RHS
End Property
Public Property Get ActualParameters() As ActualParametersType_DOCUMENTI
    On Error Resume Next
    ActualParameters = Gvar_ActualParameters
End Property
```

I have another c# project that not references the vb6 project but needs use it.
I tried with:

```
var iet = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PROJVB6.CLASSVB6");
dynamic CalledProgram = Activator.CreateInstance(iet);
```

And it works.
But if i try to get the property ActualParameters with this:

```
dynamic a = CalledProgram.ActualParameters();
```

i receive this error:

> The specified record cannot be mapped to a managed value class.

How can i do to access to ActualParameter for set values of Codice or Numreg without generate the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `ActualParameters` is a property and not a Method.

So this would be right:

```cs
// dynamic a = CalledProgram.ActualParameters();
//                                           ^^ wrong
dynamic a = CalledProgram.ActualParameters;
```